# selenium не находит аттрибут src, хотя он там есть

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
for x in range(1, 2):
    print(x)
    with webdriver.Chrome(options=options_chrome) as browser:
        browser.get("https://russian.alibaba.com/p-detail/Show1-1600173171912.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.topad_creative.d_image.2ccf48dcAJ5VAn")
        a = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'main-item')
        print(a.get_attribute('src'))
```

На алибаба находит элемент main-item, это фотографии товара, я хочу вытянуть из этих классов srс, тобиш ссылку на фотки, но не получается и пишет None

Comment: Перешел по ссылке, посмотрел html и не нашел там элемента main-item

Comment: Посмотри в коде страницы, если нажать на "просмотреть код", то он выдает только изначальный вид страницы, а в начальном виде такого элемента нету, он подгружается динамически, а элемент main-item это фотки снизу товара

Comment: Это уточнение надо добавить в описание вопроса

Comment: после загрузки  страницы и подгрузки всех элементов в браузере -  нет такого элемента https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGgE1.png

Comment: и как бы я в галлерею не тыкал - он не появляется

Comment: проскролил до конца страницы - nicht

Comment: Элемент есть! Посмотри в элементах, а не консоле, селениум тоже ищет этот элемент, и выдает его, а вот ссылку когда использую аттрибут src не выдает